# google storage: bucket has just started caching files. What should I do to stop it?

Tags: python, caching, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I need no caching for both already uploaded files and for files which will be uploaded in the future.

For files already uploaded, I tried using gsutil setmeta but files are still being cached

For files which will be uploaded in the future, I have not made any changes in my python code.

Python code

> from google.cloud import storage
>
> from google.cloud.storage import Blob
>
> client = storage.Client()
>
> bucket = client.get_bucket('my_bucket')
>
> name = "vtt_files/test.txt"
>
> blob = storage.Blob(name, bucket)
>
> blob.upload_from_string("test213")

If I enter http://storage.googleapis.com/my_bucket/vtt_files/test.txt, 
file is cached

What should I do? Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to say how you are accessing the files and how you're observing that you're getting cached data. Please be as specific as possible - we should be able to duplicate what you're doing to reproduce the behavior. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DougStevenson done. thank you very much in advance

Comment: How can you tell that the files are being cached?

Comment: @AMC I enter file's url and it shows old content. I use download_as_string and file contents are updated

Comment: Sometimes this behavior is due to the browser, could you check if this behavior stands in Incognito mode as well?

Comment: @JoséSoni it stands in Incognito mode as well unfortunately

Comment: Could you verify what is stated on the metadata?

Answer (score 4):

This code was the solution

```
    blob = storage.Blob(to_blob, destination_bucket)
    blob.cache_control = 'no-cache'
    result = blob.upload_from_string(string)
```